# How many mappings from a 5-element set to a 2-element set s.t. every point has at least 2 preimages.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> How many mappings are there from a 5-element set $A={a,b,c,d,e}$ to a 2-element set $B=\alpha, \beta$ s.t. every point has at least 2 preimages?

It is my understanding that the total number of maps from A to B is $2^5=32$.
However, I'm not sure where to go from here. There are 2 cases where a, b, c, d, e only map to one element in the codomain. So we have $32-2=30$. Then there is the case where 4 elements of A map to $\alpha$, and 1 maps to $\beta$ and vice versa, and there are $ 4 \choose 1$ ways for each such mapping. So we have $30-2(4)=22$. Is my reasoning and answer correct?

Comment: close, it should be 5 choose 4 for one element case

Comment: The title refers to a map to a three-element set, but the question body says the codomain is a two-element set. I assume the body is right?

Comment: @BrianTung You are right, edited the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$20.$ Because $f^{-1}\{\alpha\}$ is one of the $\binom {5}{3}=10\quad$ $3$-member subsets of $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ or  $f^{-1}\{\alpha\}$ is one of the $\binom {5}{2}=10\quad$ $2$-member subsets of $\{a,b,c,d,e\}.$